# Histogram creation from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am currently analyzing a cricket dataset where I have encountered a bit of a problem. The dataset covers all games played in the IPL over a season, and the runs are recorded in two separate columns "Home runs" and "Away runs". I am attempting to create a histogram of the teams with the most total runs over a season. Below is an example of how the dataset looks.

```
Home        Away        Home runs     Away runs
Mumbai      Rajesthan    187           156
Punjab      Gujerat      165           186
Rajesthan   Punjab       201           130
Gujerat     Mumbai       170           196
```

I have attempted to merge the home and away columns to a single column as a list and use the df.explode argument to create a dataframe, without luck aswell as df.groupby on both teams and runs. Any tips on how I could solve this?

Desired output would be:

```
Mumbai     Rajesthan   Gujerat    Punjab
383        357         356        295
```

In a histogram format

Answer (score 0):

You can try concat the columns values then pivot table

```py
out = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.filter(like='Home').values, df.filter(like='Away').values]))
       .pivot_table(columns=0, values=1, aggfunc='sum')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

```
print(out)

   Gujerat  Mumbai  Punjab  Rajesthan
1      356     383     295        357
```